# C programming language exercise 2-4: I dont understand the answer

Tags: c, loops

I saw an answer in web and doesn't understand how it can work with that loop. And why mine won't work.The question is : Write an alternate version of `squeeze(s1,s2)` that deletes each character in the string `s1` that matches any character in the string `s2`. 
I think the it should check for each char in `s1` that doesn't match every character in `s2`. Like you see a character in `s1`, you loop through `s2` to see if it matches that char in `s1` and move on to the next char in `s1`. So outside loop for `s1` and inner loop for `s2`. 
here's his code , I put it in a whole code to test it. His output is correct. His code is the function part. What I don't understand is why he put `s2` in outside loop and it even works.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze2(char s[], char t[]);

void squeeze2(char s[], char t[]) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; t[k] != '\0'; k++) {
        for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (s[i] != t[k])
                s[j++] = s[i];
        s[j] = '\0';
    }
}

int main() {
    char s1[] = "hello meow meow princess";
    char s2[] = { 'a', 'e', 'm' };
    squeeze2(s1, s2);
    int i = 0;
    while (s1[i] != '\0') {
        printf("%c", s1[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And theres mine. I put S2 in inner code and its out put is hllo meow meow princess..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s1[],char s2[]);

int main() {
    char s1[] = "hello meow meow princess";
    char s2[] = { 'a', 'e', 'm' };
    squeeze(s1, s2);
    int l;
    for (l = 0; l < strlen(s1); l++)
        printf("%c", s1[l]);
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (s1[i] != '\0')
        for (int j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[i] != s2[j]) {
                s1[k] = s1[i];
                k++;
            }
            i++;
       }
}
```

Comment: Litter both codes with print functions to print the various variables, and carefully examine the code flows. That may give you some good insight in the differences between the two codes.

Comment: I was surprised that this condition `s2[j] != '\0'` works. Then I compiled with `-O3` and things failed with a bus error. `'\0'` is *not* in your `s2` string, hence you shouldn't compare against it! (In other words, either version of `squeeze` doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does not matter whether you loop first on `s1` and next on `s2` or the other way around provided that you adapt the actual code.

There is a problem in the both versions: the string `s2` in `main` is not null terminated (it is not a C string), so the behavior in `squeeze` is undefined as characters from the second string will be dereferenced beyond the end of the array.

There are more problems in your version:

- you do not null terminate `s1` in case it gets shortened if one or more of its characters was found in `s2`.
- the algorithm is broken: you copy each character of `s1` as many times as you find a character from `s2` that does not match it.

You should instead verify if the character is present in `s2`, either by calling `strchr(s2, s1[i])` or by enumerating by hand.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char *s1, const char *s2);

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "hello meow meow princess";
    char s2[] = { 'a', 'e', 'm', '\0' };
    squeeze(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0;
}

void squeeze(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = k = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j])
                break;
        }
        if (s2[j] == '\0') {  // character was not found in s2
            s1[k++] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    s1[k] = '\0'; // null terminate s1 of it was shortened
}
```

Notes:

- Always use braces for a non trivial statement after `if`, `else`, `for`, `while` and `do ... while`
- Favor `for` over `while`: grouping the initialization, increment and test of the index variable improves readability and reduces bugs.
- Avoid naming a variable `l`: with a constant width font, it looks too similar to `1`.
- `const` qualify string arguments that are not modified by the function.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean its not a c string? Doesn't all arrays or strings have an invisible '\0' in c?

Comment: @jessie: it would if you defined `s2` as `char s2[] = "aem";`, but since you expicitly made it just 3 bytes this way: `char s2[] = { 'a', 'e', 'm' };` it does not.